# Python pandas.melt how to switch row values into column name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use [pandas.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) or [pandas.pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)
to convert rows from Column Food-Type into Column headings and Dates into row.

```
Food-Type  2021 Oct-21   Nov-21
Banana      104  104.4   105.5
cereals    105.7  105.8  106.5
Rice       97.6   97.5   98.2
```

The end result should be like this.

```
         Banana  cereals   Rice
 2021    104      105.7    105.5
 Oct-21  104.4    105.8    106.5
 Nov-21  105.5    97.5     98.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [transposition](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), after setting `Food-Type` as index:

```
out = df.set_index('Food-Type').T
```

Output:

```
Food-Type  Banana  cereals  Rice
2021        104.0    105.7  97.6
Oct-21      104.4    105.8  97.5
Nov-21      105.5    106.5  98.2
```

Alternative:

```
out = df.set_index('Food-Type').T.rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Output:

```
        Banana  cereals  Rice
2021     104.0    105.7  97.6
Oct-21   104.4    105.8  97.5
Nov-21   105.5    106.5  98.2
```